# Add canvas between text in itext 7

Tags: java, canvas, itext, itext7

Is it possible to add  canvas  along with the addParagraph to the document?
i have long text(1000 page).

I need to add canvas between text in certain places(graphics, shapes, etc.).

For example, if there is a word  "graph_add" in the text

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
PageSize ps = PageSize.A4;;
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, ps);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bigfileWithText.txt"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
if(line =="graph_add")
//Add canvas in document in this place!!
doc.add(new Paragraph(line)
}
doc.close();
```

Comment: That's not clear what you want to achieve. What do you mean by adding canvas? How does it differ from adding a paragraph to the document?

Comment: I just need to add different shapes, graphics to certain places to be drawn.

Comment: Have you tried PdfCanvas functionality? It's well described here: https://itextpdf.com/ru/resources/books/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-adding-content-canvas-or-document

Comment: I saw it, here i need to create on a separate page. I need to go text and in a certain moment after the text was added a figure